# Handling global variables when writing OpenGL with glut(or freeglut)

Tags: opengl, global-variables, glut

I am learning `OpenGL` with the `glut` library. The problem is that when the program grows, there are so many `global variables` to handle. as so many people have said it is a nono to use too many `global variables` in the program. However, I can't substitute the `global variables` by passing the user defined parameters to the callback functions defined by glut. For example:

```
void display (void)
{
   // How to pass user defined parameters here?
   // some more code
}
int
main(void)
{
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    // some more code
}
```

So my questions is this:

1. How to handle the global variables when writing OpenGL with glut?
2. Is there any other ways to substitute the global variables instead of passing the parameters to functions
3. How does other libs(not glut) handling the input/output of OpenGL deal with global variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of "no global variables" is incomplete. The actual wording is "no global variables to pass parameters between functions". However global variables are fine to hold global, program wide state.

> How to handle the global variables when writing OpenGL with glut?

If the state you're managing is program state, then globals are fine, actually. Window dependent state can be retrieved using `glutGet`. Don't forget, that OpenGL itself is one large global state machine. There's one global OpenGL context per thread and switching the context actually changes a global variable.

Don't use the GLUT reshape function for things related to rendering, i.e. don't set viewport and projection in reshape. Do it in the display function.

> Is there any other ways to substitute the global variables instead of passing the parameters to functions

There are some ways, like using the *ffcall* library to turn parametized functions into closures which you can pass to GLUT.

> How does other libs(not glut) handling the input/output of OpenGL deal with global variables?

Either by allowing to pass a data parameter to the callback functions (big design failure in GLUT, not allowing for that), or using a message/signal based system instead of callbacks.

Comment: actually I have to pass many global variables between functions. for example, when I strike the space key which change the value of `stepsize` defined as global variable and handled in the `keyboard` callback functions. The `stepsize` need to be passed to the `display` callback functions to change the distance between the viewer and the objects(for example). Another example is that when I initialize the texture objects(in the `init()` func) which have to be global to pass into the `display` function. is it handled right? or there is better solutions?

Comment: @tlh1987: your callback functions should not pass data to display, but change program state. And program state is, by definition, global. You'd need a truly functional language (like Lisp, Scheme, OCaml or Haskell) to effectively manage program state through function parametization. But C is mostly imperative, to you will have some global state somewhere.

Comment: Hm... actually, I did't understand the meaning of `change the program state`, I don't know how to change the `program state` in the keyboard callback function. as my former comment to handle the global variables stepsize is not a good idea, could you please give me a practical solution? I just have gone through the red book about OpenGL and don't know much about the functional languages.

Comment: "Program state" is just the term that covers all the data a program holds and on which its functions operate on. Program state of a game would be for example the loaded map, player positions and stats. At some point you have to keep them in a program wide variable. If you have a document centric approach, you'll have some master document structure, from which everything else branches off. But in the case of GLUT-ish programs, you don't have multiple documents or worlds or similar. So putting the state into globals is just fine. For anything complex you should abandon GLUT anyway.